# What is the most viewed question on Science Fiction?

Tags: discussion, support

Simple question, What is the most viewed question on Science Fiction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[In what order should the Star Wars movies be watched?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/in-what-order-should-the-star-wars-movies-be-watched)

With over 1 million views, it wipes the floor with all other questions where views are concerned.

The second most viewed is [How did the zombie outbreak start in the Walking Dead?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11325/how-did-the-zombie-outbreak-start-in-the-walking-dead) with less than 600,000 views. You can see the top 1000 most viewed questions with [this Data.SE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/463419/posts-with-most-views).

Comment: Awesome, now that is a question for the ages!!!

Comment: @KyloRen It also shows how pointless the "people reached" statistic is. Several people who've contributed a single low-voted answer to that thread and almost nothing else to the site have "reached" more people than I have with my 500 answers and >150 questions. </grumble>

Comment: Not as sophisticated as a data.se query, but you could also use the “views” option to limit your [search](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+views%3A500000).

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Astoundingly, [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112473/20774) (directly quoting **the guy who made the filmson what order they should be watched** ) has received precisely one upvote... :-(

Comment: @Richard You were too late to the party ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Since I posted, over 100,000 people have viewed the question. Only one of them found the answer helpful.

Comment: @Richard I wonder how many of those 100,000 bothered scrolling down far enough to even see your answer ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Good question, dunno. It's hard to say whether people just don't find Lucas useful.

Comment: @Richard - I believe that was mine. On a smaller scale, [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108130/55866) to the Ender's Game one (which is by far the most extensive posted there and also the only one  which is up-to-date) has only five upvotes.

Comment: @Richard I don't think people care what Lucas has to say about much of anything at this point. I didn't upvote that one either. What do I care what celebrities think? The only one of those quotes that is useful is the one from Seitz, but I don't know who he is and I think that order and logic are already in other answers.

Comment: @DCShannon - Nah, what possible input do we need from the guy who was responsible for conceiving, financing, co-writing, producing and directing the films? Lucas-bashing certainly seems to be in vogue but it sickens me.

Comment: @Richard Based on what he did when he had access to more money and technology, and his assertion that that was what he wanted to do all along, it seems to me (and I'm sure others) that we were lucky he wasn't able to make the films he wanted initially, and so was he. Whatever creative spark he may have had in the 70s and 80s, I'm convinced it's gone, and that the movies I want to see aren't the ones he's trying to make. Therefore, his recommendation on how to best experience the movies is pretty worthless. I don't *want* to experience them the way he intends.

Comment: @DCShannon - Gotta disagree. For all their flaws, the prequel trilogy still comprises three exceptional films. They even wrote Jar Jar out of the second and third films, so it's not like Lucas wasn't listening to fan-reaction.